# Lexicographic combination algorithm

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

How can the lexicographic combination algorithm find all possible combination?

[image]

To me this code generates the following combination (2 of 4 counting from 0 to 3):

1. 0 1
2. 0 2
3. 1 2
4. 1 3
5. 2 3

But 0 3 is missing. This is because once you flip a 0 to 1 as from (2.) and (3.), there is no way to start over with 0. But because the gap between 0 2 in (2.) is greater than 1 the 0 needs to be incremented. What am I missing? Because it should generate 0 3 too.

The code is from the book "The Art of computer programming"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combination (0 3) does get generated, just not in the position you might expect.

Here's a direct translation of the algorithm into Java:

```
static void lex(int t, int n)
{
    int[] c = new int[t+3];
    for(int j=1; j<=t; j++) c[j] = j-1;
    c[t+1] = n;
    c[t+2] = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        for(int i=t; i>=1; i--) 
            System.out.print(c[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();

        int j=1;
        while(c[j]+1 == c[j+1])
        {
            c[j] = j-1;
            j += 1;
        }

        if(j > t) return;

        c[j] += 1;
    }
}
```

`lex(2, 4)` produces:

```
1 0 
2 0 
2 1 
3 0 
3 1 
3 2
```

Which is certainly ordered, just not the order you'd expect if you consider that 0 should come before 1 etc..

Here's a previous [discussion](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/112361/which-order-is-lexicographic-order) on the various meanings of "lexicographic" and how Knuth's interpretation compares to others.

Comment: Thank you. I guess the point I was missing was that after (2 1) and 1 is at position j=1 needs to be set to j-1 which is 0. which leads to (2 0) but 2 is also increased, leading to (3 0)